# Hadoop - `hdfs dfs -ls` versus ls

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I connect to a Hadoop cluster at work using `ssh`.
There seems to be two different file systems available from there :
 - one local (although it's remote since I'm sshing this machine). I can navigate the file system using `cd ..` and show files in there using `ls`. I can also install some programs here.
 - one not local using hadoop commands (`hdfs dfs ...`)

I don't understand how these two file system work together ?
Is the local kind of the master node of the hadoop cluster from which I can execute hive ?

Answer (score 1):

> :Is the local kind of the master node of the hadoop cluster from which I can execute hive ?

HIve is seemingly unrelated to the question asked since  Hive is installed completely separately from Hadoop and HDFS. Whatever machine you access needs a Hive Client for it to work, and there's no "master node" from which `hive` (although `beeline` should be used instead) cli needs to run. JDBC drivers to the HiveServer would be more useful than a terminal session for most users. Or convince your company to install Hue as a web UI for Hadoop & Hive access.

You don't necessarily need to SSH to any server to access anything if you go over the Hadoop/Hive installation pages and can gather the correct network information of servers and ports for establishing a remote connection to the Hadoop environment, but your company probably wouldn't like that from a security perspective. At that point, your local machine would be configured exactly the same way as the "jump box" or "edge node" as they are called.

> one local (although it's remote since I'm sshing this machine)

Yup. Not Hadoop filesystem. All machines you SSH into have a local hard drive. You need to  SFTP / SCP files there  before you copy them to HDFS.

> one not local using hadoop commands (hdfs dfs ...) I don't understand how these two file system work together ?

If you've SSH'd into a datanode, Hadoop will still store data on the local filesystem, however, it's not entire files, but broken apart pieces of them called blocks. Hadoop uses many, many machines and disks to create a distributed filesystem abstraction, hence the name HDFS.

If your company uses a NAS or FTP file server, it's a similar concept. You could SSH into one of those too, with the correct permissions, however, there's a dedicated location on their local disks where files are served from.

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs..` execute commands on a **Distributed** file system hosted by your Hadoop cluster.

It is not related at all to the local file system of the server you ssh to (which can be any server with Hadoop client libraries). Actually you don't even need to ssh. You can access HDFS files from your desktop with REST APIs https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN

Do you refer to Hive Clients (see all the options here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93NewCommandLineShell) or Hive Server?

Comment: "It's not related at all". Except you can use `hadoop fs -ls file://` to see local filesystem